How do I reference data in front-matter?
I have a base.njk layout that sets the title based on frontmatter:
---
title: My Site
---
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content | safe }}
  </body>
</html>

Later, I'm creating pages from data. However, I also want to set a title in the front matter. Here's the example from the eleventy docs, but with the title: key added to the front matter:
/* _data/possums.json */
[
    {
        name: "Fluffy",
        age: 2,
    },
    {
        name: "Snugglepants",
        age: 5,
    },
    {
        name: "Lord Featherbottom",
        age: 4,
    },
    {
        name: "Pennywise",
        age: 9,
    },
];

<!-- possum-pages.njk -->
---
pagination:
  data: possums
  size: 1
  alias: possum
permalink: "possums/{{ possum.name | slugify }}/"
title: "{{ possum.name }}"
---

{{ possum.name }} is {{ possum.age }} years old

However, when the page is rendered, it literally writes <title>{{ possum.name }}</title> instead of the expected <title>Fluffy</title>. How do I get eleventy to reference my data in my front matter?

You want to use computed data in a template string.
If you put your title key in an eleventyComputed: section, it will render as expected:
---
pagination:
  data: possums
  size: 1
  alias: possum
permalink: "possums/{{ possum.name | slugify }}/"
eleventyComputed:
  title: "{{ possum.name }}"
---

{{ possum.name }} is {{ possum.age }} years old

